# Xcode 7 breakpoint log message doesn't reliably include expression results

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7.1 to develop a project that I'm trying to debug, and have attempted to do so using breakpoint log messages while invoking my functions via unit tests. However, it appears that I've either misunderstood something about breakpoint logging, or uncovered a bug in Xcode: when I attempt to use breakpoint logging within a function, the log message does not include the value of the incoming parameter, although it does include a local variable.

For example, given this struct:

```
struct Foo: CustomStringConvertible  {
    var s: String

    func printAFoo(fooToPrint: Foo) {
        let i=1
        // Breakpoint message text:
        //   %B From debugger: fooToPrint=@fooToPrint@; i=@i@
        print("printAFoo: From code: \(fooToPrint); i:\(i)")
    }

}

// MARK: - CustomStringConvertible
extension Foo {
    var description: String {
        return "\(s)"
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint debugging message at the indicated line and invoke as follows:

```
let foo = Foo(s: "Original string")
foo.printAFoo(foo)
```

And get the output:

```
printAFoo(_:) From debugger: fooToPrint=; i=1
printAFoo: From code: Original string; i:1
```

I've noticed this behavior is inconsistent: I originally was troubleshooting this issue against a mutating function and noticed that the breakpoint log message wasn't printing *any* `@expr@` tagged values (including the local `i` variable), but was printing all of them as expected in a non-mutating function. As I continued to poke around, I saw that the incoming parameter expression stopped logging for the non-mutating function as well.

I suspect this is a bug, but wanted to ask if anybody else had seen it, or knew of a workaround other than using `print` statements in the body of the code.

Comment: Are you running your tests in Release config or Debug config?

Comment: I was afraid of that. :(

Comment: I have another question: does this work when you run your app normally but not when you run it from a unit test? Or does it just _never_ work?

Comment: @matt It doesn't work in either case, unfortunately. I added the invocation above to my main view controller's `viewDidLoad:`, and got the same behavior as described above.

Comment: Well, I'd file a bug report (esp. since you seem to have whittled it down to a super-simple demo).

Comment: As a workaround: do things work any better if you promote the variable referred to in the `@expr@` to an instance or global variable? If they do, at least this would get you where you want to go (and we'd know that the issue is locals).

Comment: My original troubleshooting was on a function that wouldn't display *any* @expr@, including local variables or even `@1+1@`. In my demo above, even a local var `let s = fooToPrint` does not display (although `let s = "locally assigned value"` does, go figure). Thanks for the suggestions. I've filed a [bug with Apple](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6040500289142784).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Sorry it's not behaving as advertised but your work on this will help others!

Comment: One minor correction: assigning a local *string* variable displayed; assigning a local `Foo` variable did not display. So it seems tied to the struct somehow.